# Can I flag questions for migration?

Tags: support, flags, moderation

Can a flag questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755613/are-there-any-websites-where-i-can-just-download-images-for-menus-icons-graphic) for migration?  (By the time someone reads, it might get migrated but my point is - can I flag a question for things like migration, retagging, etc)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `flag` link (with the [new and improved flagging dialog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/improved-flagging/)):

```
flag
  -> it doesn't belong here
     -> off topic
        -> webmasters
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't touch the button as I didn't know it would show this dialogue :)

Comment: Only about 5 options using that approach =) Was hoping to see the math exchange there

Comment: When I click 'flag' I do not see any option for 'It doesn't belong here'. Has this been changed?

Comment: @Despertar that option is only available when flagging _questions_ `:)`