# Where can I suggest to move a question to another Stack Exchange site?

Tags: support, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I flag questions for migration?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75764/can-i-flag-questions-for-migration)

I'm not an admin and have no power to do it myself.

For example, the question *[Really “wow” them in the interview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329289/really-wow-them-in-the-interview)* should (I think) be at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: As per your question about the post -- I believe [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92112/is-the-career-development-tag-a-honeypot/92163#92163) partially addresses why it's relevant to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You click flag, then "it doesn't belong here" and then "off topic".  If there are options you can select one, but some sites (like Meta) don't have any options, so just flag it and the mods will move it.

Comment: If you like you can also post in a comment, this question belongs on superuser.com (etc).